# IOS opacity transition not a nice effect

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview, webkit

Making some simple animation using CSS and JS for UIWebView; testing and debugging with Chrome;
For animation using this style:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
```

setting Opacity from 0 to 1;
Everything looks fine except the final state of animation, when last animated element () appears, a random block of text on the page gets a little bolder. 
Already tried different solutions:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
opacity: 0.999;
```

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

after reading other discussions about problems with animations, tryed to use this solutions:

```
.flick-fix
{
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

but this class should be applied to the element wich behavior is looks strange, instead of the animated object;